# Data binding xaml elements so i can remove them

Tags: c#, xaml

Is there a way to bind directly to an element object itself.

I am currently showing and hiding elements, but I would prefer to remove them entirely as they will never need to be used.

Is there a way to do a databinding to an element and then just remove it if required for that specific item?

for example, let's say I have participants in a conversation, ==1, ==2 or >3

```
<Border Visibility="{Binding ParticipantImagesOneVisibility}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5">
    <Image Source="{Binding Participants[0].image.thumbnail_link}" Width="62" Height="62" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Border>
<Border Visibility="{Binding ParticipantImagesTwoVisibility}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="31" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="31"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Participants[0].image.thumbnail_link}" Width="31" Height="62" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Participants[1].image.thumbnail_link}" Width="31" Height="62" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
<Border Visibility="{Binding ParticipantImagesThreeVisibility}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5">
    <Grid Width="62" Height="62">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="31" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="31"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="31" />
            <RowDefinition Height="31"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Participants[0].image.thumbnail_link}" Width="31" Height="31" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Participants[1].image.thumbnail_link}" Width="31" Height="31" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Participants[2].image.thumbnail_link}" Width="31" Height="62" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Instead of just hiding them (which is daymmmmm slow maynnnnnn), is there a way of either generating them on the fly (ive never used a custom control) or just removing them as I come to them?

I'm specifically talking about:

`{Binding ParticipantImagesOneVisibility}` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an ItemsControl, ListBox, or ListView. Use a DataTemplate for the items. Now you bind the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection of all these participants.

Now, in your business layer, you have the participants and the list of them. If a participant drops off, the participant should be removed from the ObservableCollection. The UI will auto update because it is an ObservableCollection. Similar if a participant is added.

Comment: But what about setting all the styles etc? you can see the different grid columns and rows etc, i'm applying styling depending on if there is 1, 2, or >3 participants.

Comment: Use a custom DataTemplateSelector that selects a template based on the number of participants.

Comment: Mate, that sounds like exactly what I need! Looks complex though!

Comment: It sounds complex but when you are done, you will find it is actually less complex and more maintainable than pretty much any other option.

Comment: For others: http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/01/windows-phone-template-selector-a-design-time-solution/

Comment: got it to work brah! It's freaking awesomeeeee yehaaaaa